# In vim, how do I start vim at the end of the file and what commands are available with -c

Tags: vim

By reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464088/how-do-i-start-vim-in-insert-mode#11464158) I learned that you can give `-c` to `vim` such that it will call a command. The question is then answered by calling `vim -c startinsert`. Good, but what if I want to give other commands? I only know the shortcuts like `i` for `:startinsert`.

For example I'd like to write `vim -c gotoend` but it doesn't exists.

After some reading, all `:` commands, which are `ex` commands are written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051712/why-some-commands-in-vim-require-a-colon-while-some-dont#14051959) and in `man vim`, but where do I find a lis or method to know what can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:help :normal`. Also note that instead of `-c command` you can use `+command`.

With that, I'd typically say `vim +"norm G" foo.txt` to start at the bottom. You could even alias it: `alias vimbottom='vim +"norm G"'`; then you can use `vimbottom foo.txt` to start at the bottom, if you prefer.

> where do I find a lis or method to know what can be done

There is no better resource for Vim than its `:help`. And I don't know any place that has all the ex-commands in one place, since it would be a huge list. (EDIT: `:help :index` actually has that. Thanks, Christian Brabandt!)

Comment: See `:h :index`

Answer (score 4):

The commands for options `-c` are called ex-command named after [ex(tendended line editor)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_(text_editor)). The list of commands are in [vimdoc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/vimindex.html#ex-cmd-index) and [vimhelp](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/index.txt.html#ex-cmd-index).

The command to jump to the end of file is just `:$` so you can do this in command line:

```
vim -c $ <file>
```

Please note you probably better escape or quote `$` as it's a shell metacharacter:

```
vim -c \$ <file>
```

or

```
vim -c '$' <file>
```